# Docker push error "413 Request Entity Too Large"

Tags: docker-registry

I setup the `registry v2` and use `nginx` as reverse proxy. When I push the image to registy, it error out `413 Request Entity Too Large`.

I have modify the client_max_body_size as 20MB in nginx.conf. The push still fails.

```
client_max_body_size 20M;
```

What is the body size in docker push? How can I limit the body size?

Answer (score 53):

Docker documentation [mentions](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/nginx/) the limit should be turned off:

```
http {
    ...
    # disable any limits to avoid HTTP 413 for large image uploads
    client_max_body_size 0;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Disappointing there isn't a better fix when the [protocol](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#/blob-upload) supports chunked uploads.

Answer (score 48):

For anyone getting this error in **Kubernetes** you need to add [this annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#custom-max-body-size) to the registry Ingress resource:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
```

Answer (score 5):

You should increase the available memory to 300 MB with:

```
client_max_body_size 300M;
```

Comment: Images can be easily larger than 300M. It is better to turn off the limit: `client_max_body_size 0;`