# GitHub Actions Docker build and push failed to copy: unexpected status: 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

I have been trying to build and push my Docker images through GitHub Actions and push them to my Docker Registry.

For this I have been using the following workflow file:

```
name: Docker publish

on:
  push:
    branches: [ develop ]

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:

  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

      - name: Login to registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          registry: https://registry.domain.com
          username: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Build and push web
        id: docker_build_web
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          push: true
          context: ./web
          tags: registry.domain.com/web:latest

      - name: Build and push api
        id: docker_build_api
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          push: true
          context: ./api
          tags: registry.domain.com/api:latest
```

It all works well until it starts building the first image of the web project, which is an Angular project. After some time building the web image, it gives the error:

> Error: buildx call failed with: error: failed to solve: rpc error:
> code = Unknown desc = failed to copy: unexpected status: 413 Request
> Entity Too Large

I have looked for quite a while now, but can not seem to find a fix for the problem or even the reason why this issue is happening. My only guess at the moment is that my images are too large.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for this, this has to do with **registry nginx body limit**.

As referenced here: [Docker push error "413 Request Entity Too Large"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35122918/docker-push-error-413-request-entity-too-large)

Comment: That link refers to configuring Docker Registry, not a GitHub Action build action.

Comment: @MatthewSetter The issue is related to reverse proxy configured before the self hosted registry OP is using to push the image in Github Action. `https://registry.domain.com`